# Sql Server upper lower and index logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, uppercase, lowercase

I have FirstName and LastName columns in sql..
I want to make First Name's first letter big and the rests low
same LastName's first letter big and rests low 
For example : we have FisrtName and LastName is john sinatra name 
mine must  be John Sinatra.
how T-SQL code should be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    UPPER(LEFT(FirstName, 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(FirstName, LEN(FirstName) - 1)) AS FirstName,
    UPPER(LEFT(LastName, 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(LastName, LEN(LastName) - 1)) AS LastName
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks drumboog it solved my problem...But I am curious about am I need index logic ?

Comment: You shouldn't need an index for selecting the data... only if you were trying to filter by FirstName/LastName.  And in that case, there is no need to worry about changing the case since SQL Server is case-insensitive.

Comment: yes you are right.sure sql server is case-insensetive.Also I dont understand what you mean (only if you were trying to filter by FirstName/LastName) this. if you tell I will appreciate .thanks

Comment: I wouldn't think an index would be needed for anything that is in the select list.  An index is used for fields that you are joining on or that are in the 'where' clause.  They allow the DB to locate records faster, but they wouldn't be useful when manipulating the data in the select list.

Comment: Can you tell specific example for this situation ? if I asked more sorry :)

Comment: If you wanted to say `SELECT * from MyTable WHERE FirstName = 'John'`, then it may be useful to have an index on the FirstName field.

Comment: how useful ? can you open it a little more ?